# How to use async mocha before() initialization without setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking, mocha.js

I am using Mocha to test out some database queries I created. I need my before `block` to create the appropriate foreign keys so the unit tests can focus on testing out the raw create/delete functionality of my Node ORM.

My problem is that I am inserting db entries in my `before` block and the unit tests are running before the `before` block is finished executing.

[I read that promises should be used to deal](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/08/17/asynchronous-unit-tests-with-mocha-promises-and-winjs/) with this kind of thing, so I refactored my codebase to use promises but I still can't get around the fact that I need a setTimeout.

How can I perform async `before` block without needing to wrap my first `it` block in a `setTimeout`?

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var db = require('../server/db/config');
var models = require('../server/db/models');

describe('scoring', function() {

  var testMessage = {
    x: 37.783599,
    y: -122.408974,
    z: 69,
    message: 'Brooks was here'
  };

  var messageId = 1;

  before(function() {
    var token = '' + Math.random();
    models.createUser(token).then(function() {
      testMessage.userToken = token;
      models.insert(testMessage)
    });
  });

  it('should have votes created in db when createVote is called', function(done) {
    setTimeout(function(done) {
      models.createVote(messageId, token, function(err, res) {
        expect(res.insertId).to.be.a('number');
        done();
      });
    }.bind(this, done), 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like [joews suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579586/1906307). However, Mocha supports using promises for synchronization. You have to return your promise:

```
before(function() {
    var token = '' + Math.random();
    return models.createUser(token).then(function() {
      testMessage.userToken = token;
      models.insert(testMessage)
    });
});
```

Mocha won't continue to the test until it is able to execute `.then` on the promise returned by your code.

Answer (score 1):

The function you pass to `before`, like the other Mocha API methods, can accept a `done` callback. You should call this when your `before` actions have completed:

```
before(function(done) {
  var token = '' + Math.random();
  models.createUser(token).then(function() {
    testMessage.userToken = token;
    return models.insert(testMessage)
  }).then(function() {
    done();
  })
});
```

[Mocha docs - asynchronous code](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)