# Making a request before all tests start in Mocha

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, mocha.js, axios

I would like to test my simple API that has `/groups` URL.
I want to make an API request to that URL (using Axios) before all tests begin and make the response visible to all test functions.

I am trying to make the `response` visible but not able to make it work. I followed a similar case [with filling out the DB upfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579487/how-to-use-async-mocha-before-initialization-without-settimeout) but no luck with my case.

My simple test file below:

```
var expect  = require('chai').expect
var axios = require('axios')
var response = {};
describe('Categories', function() {    
    describe('Groups', function() {
        before(function() {
            axios.get(config.hostname + '/groups').then(function (response) {                                                            
                return response;
            })                
        });

        it('returns a not empty set of results', function(done) {
            expect(response).to.have.length.greaterThan(0);
            done();            
        })
    });    
});
```

I tried also a sligh modification of `before` function:

```
before(function(done) {
    axios.get(config.hostname + '/groups')
         .then(function (response) {                                                            
             return response;
         }).then(function() {
             done();
         })      
    });
```

but no luck too.

The error I am getting is simply that `response` isn't changing nor is visible within `it`. *AssertionError: expected {} to have property 'length'*

**Summarising:** How can I pass `response` from axios inside to `in()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first form is incorrect, because you're not returning the chained promise. As such, mocha has no way of knowing when your `before` is finished, or even that it's async at all. Your second form will solve this problem, but since `axios.get` already returns a promise, it's kind of a waste not to use mocha's built-in promise support.

As for making the response visible in the `it`, you need to assign it to a variable in a scope that  will be visible within the `it`.

```
var expect  = require('chai').expect
var axios = require('axios')
var response;
describe('Categories', function() {
    describe('Groups', function() {
        before(function() {
            // Note that I'm returning the chained promise here, as discussed.
            return axios.get(config.hostname + '/groups').then(function (res) {
                // Here's the assignment you need.
                response = res;
            })
        });

        // This test does not need the `done` because it is not asynchronous.
        // It will not run until the promise returned in `before` resolves.
        it('returns a not empty set of results', function() {
            expect(response).to.have.length.greaterThan(0);
        })
    });
});
```